# Java split a string and convert one of them to double

Tags: java, string, split, double

Just a quick java question here... I want to split a string and get a specific part to convert it to a double:

```
String name = "England vs Spain -- $13.50";
```

What's the easiest way to get 13.50 as a double.
I was thinking of splitting them into two first, the words, and then the dollar value. Using .split("--");

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Yes. Good idea it is. go-ahead.

Comment: Why cant you split by  $  ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Double.valueOf(name.split("\\$")[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a *regular expression*, compile a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and use a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). Something like,

```
String name = "England vs Spain -- $13.50";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\s*--\\s*\\$(.+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Words: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.printf("Amount: $%.2f%n", Double.parseDouble(m.group(2)));
}
```

Output is

```
Words: England vs Spain 
Amount: $13.50
```